# Understanding of the regexp match feature of the expr utility

Tags: expr

Could anyone help me to understand how the regex match works with the `expr` utility? I've read its man page and below is an excerpt:

```
STRING : REGEXP
  anchored pattern match of REGEXP in STRING
```

But I can't understand how it works. I did some testing:

```
[root@192 ~]# expr "abc" : '.*'
3
[root@192 ~]# expr "abc" : 'b.*'
0
[root@192 ~]#
```

What is `expr` doing in these two commands? For the first command, it seems `expr` found a match from the first character of `abc` and reports the matched length. But why does it produce `0` for the second command? I just don't understand the logic here.

Btw, I know how regexes work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relevant part of the quoted manpage is that these are *anchored* matches. This means that the regex will need to match the entire string, from the beginning to the end. So your `.*` is actually `^.*$`. The man page is admittedly not very clear, but yes, it looks like it will print the length of the match by default:

```
$ expr "abc" : '.*'
3
```

You can apparently get it to print the match itself using capture groups:

```
$ expr "abc" : '\(.*\)'
abc
$ expr "abc" : '.\(b.\)'
bc
```